# Dart return keyword in an async function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

Can somebody please tell me why the `return "NOK"` code get executed anyway even if the status is true?
Is this not the purpose of **return** keyword to stop the function execution and return the value? Or do i miss something about async functions or Dart langage itself?

```dart
static dynamic getUserRef() async {
    // HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    bool status;
    await InfosHelper.getInfo('testinfo').then((response) {
      InfoModel info = InfoModel.fromJson(response.data);
      status = info.status;
      Map<String, dynamic> otherData = info.data;
      if (status) {
        return "OK";
      }
    });

    return "NOK";
  }
```

Comment: try this one 
>>>>>>>>

  static Future<String> getUserRef() async {
    // HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    bool status;
    final TaskSnapshot a = await InfosHelper.getInfo('testinfo');
    InfoModel info = InfoModel.fromJson(a.ref.data);
      status = info.status;
      Map<String, dynamic> otherData = info.data;
      
   
    if (status) {
      return "OK";
    }else if (status==false){
      return "NOK";
    }else{
      print(status);
      return "NOK";
      
    }
    
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling .then which is a method it self so the status true will stop execution of .then method but the main getUserRef with always return 'Nok'

```
 static dynamic getUserRef() async {
    // HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    bool status;
    var response=await InfosHelper.getInfo('testinfo');
     if (response!=null){
  InfoModel info=InfoModel.fromJson(response.data);
   Map<String, dynamic> otherData = info.data;
  if(info.status){
return 'ok';
}
else{
return 'nok'}
}
}
else{
//Error
}
```

Comment: Ah OK. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 static Future<String> getUserRef() async {
        // HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();            
        final response = await InfosHelper.getInfo('testinfo');
        InfoModel info = InfoModel.fromJson(response.data);
        bool status = info.status;
        Map<String, dynamic> otherData = info.data;
         
        return status ? "OK" : "NOK";
                
      }
```